# Invalid pointer addition

Tags: c++, radstudio

Не понимаю, в одном проекте такой кусок кода работал с БД MSSQL, а здесь выдает ошибку, что в том проекте, я объявил глобальную переменную, что в этом, рез-т ошибка в этом случае

```
Memo1->Text = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id = "+test+"");
```

Не берет переменную, хотя в другом проекте, вот такой же код, даже с двумя переменными работает

```
Memo1->Text = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select вопрос from "+ntl+" where id = "+nq+"");
```

К базе подключено, если вместо переменной test, поставить цифру, то все работает, но мне нужен счетчик, в чем причина?

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
int test = 1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Memo1->Text = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select Исполнитель from 
Исполнители where id = "+test+"");
test++ ;
}
```

Весь код

Код работающего примера, приведу отрывок, ибо слишком много кода, лишнее убрал

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
int nq = 1, c = 0, ot = 0,t = 0;
String nt;
String tab;
String ntl;
// Пройти тест
void __fastcall TForm1::N3Click(TObject *Sender)
{

nq = 1;
Label2->Caption = nq;
ntl = InputBox("Тест", "Введите имя", "");
Button8->Visible = true;
Memo1->Text = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select вопрос from "+ntl+" where 
id = "+nq+"");
Button1->Caption = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select О1 from "+ntl+" 
where id = "+nq+"");
Button2->Caption = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select О2 from "+ntl+" 
where id = "+nq+"");
if (FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select О3 from "+ntl+" where id = "+nq+"") 
!= "")
{
Button3->Visible = true;
Button3->Caption = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select О3 from "+ntl+" 
where id = "+nq+"");
}
if (FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select О4 from "+ntl+" where id = "+nq+"") 
!= "")
{
Button4->Visible = true;
Button4->Caption = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select О4 from "+ntl+" 
where id = "+nq+"");
}
}
```

[image: Вот первый скрин]

[image: Второй что изменилось, на нужное в базе]

Comment: В другом проекте с двумя переменными, наверное `ntl` и `nq` не типа int

Comment: Работоспособность такого кода зависить от типов использованных переменных. Что там у вас за переменные в "работающих" примерах - не ясно. Ваш код с `test` ошибочен, как компилятор вам правильно сказал. И не надо выдумывать, что при подстановке "цифры" вместо переменной "все работает" - ошибка будет точно такая же. И в первую очередь пишите, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Зачем вы пытаетесь прибавить число к строковому литералу?

Comment: nq наоборот тип int, а вот ntl, это String, но это чтобы я открыл нужную таблицу с помощью ntl
Зачем мне выдумывать? Если при изменении на цифру все работает

Comment: Ну так покажите нам ваш вариант с "цифрой", который якобы "работает".

Comment: Да без проблем.

Comment: Нет, нет, нет. Вы сказали, что если заменить `test` на цифру, то все работает. "Заменить `test` на цифру" означет вот это: `"select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id = "+2+""`. И работать это не будет - та же ошибка.

Comment: если заменить "+test+" на цифру 1, то все работает
Ведь по клику, он должен выдать, а уже потом прибавить к test +1

Comment: Я же говорил, что вы выдумываете! В оригинале было *"вместо переменной test поставить цифру"*, а теперь вдруг откуда не возьмись стало *"заменить "+test+" на цифру 1"*. А это уже совсем другая история. С чего это вдруг в замену включились и плюсы и кавычки?

Comment: Какой смысл мне выдумывать?????
Если я сделаю вот так:
Memo1->Text = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id = 1");
То все работает

А мне нужно так
Memo1->Text = FDConnection1->ExecSQLScalar("select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id = "+test+"");
Как в примере работающем выложил, посмотри внимательно, там как написано, там переменная nq глобальная, она как счетчик увеличения, каждый раз берет из базы по id, а в базе, id с идентифиикатором

Comment: Ужос... Где вариант, в котором переменная `test` заменена на цифру? Вот это ваше `"select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id = 1"` - это НЕ замена переменной `test` на цифру, это полная и неузнаваемая переделка всего выражения. Даю под запись, для обязательного зазубривания: замена `test` на цифу будет выглядеть так: `"select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id ="+ 1 + ""`. И компилироваться это не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если самый первый бинарный оператор `+` в вашем выражении содержит объект типа `String` в качестве одного из своих операндов, то используется перегруженный оператор `+` для типа `String`, который очевидно выполняет конкатенацию строк. Результат работы такого оператора очевидно имеет тип `String`, то приводит к тому, что и все остальные операторы `+` в выражении интерпретируются как тот же самый перегруженный оператор `+` для типа `String`. Именно поэтому работают ваши примеры с переменной `ntl`, которая имеет тип `String`.

В вашем ошибочном выражении

```
"select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id = "+test+""
```

тип `String` не участвует вообще. В выражении участвуют только строковые литералы и целочисленные переменные. Выражение ошибочно, что вам компилятор ясно и сказал. Первый оператор `+` в этом выражении еще формально корректен (хоть и делает совсем не то, что вы хотели), а вот второй уже совершенно не корректен.

Если вы хотите именно конкатенации строк (в т.ч. строковых представлений чисел), выполняемой оператором `+` для типа `String`, то позаботьтесь о том, чтобы с самого начала выражение вычислялось в рамках типа `String`

```
String("select Исполнитель from Исполнители where id = ") + test + ""
```

Comment: Я не хочу склеивать строки, это как счетчик, переменная используется
Я каждый раз по нажатию, увеличиваю счетчик и изменяю текст в Memo1, на текст из базы

Comment: @Максим: Что??? Тот код, который у вас работает, занимается именно склеиванием строк. Поэтому что вы хотите сказать своим "я не хочу склеивать строки" мне в упор не ясно. Вам надо приклеить к строке строковое представление вашего счетчика. Именно склеивание строк вы делаете и хотите делать. Если вы даже этого не понимаете, то боюсь тут все безнадежно.

Comment: Хотя нет, сори, так все работает, но я не понимаю тогда, почему в прошлом примере, все работало без этого?

Comment: @Максим: Мой ответ как раз и начинается с объяснения того, почему "в прошлом примере все работало".

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения и терпение